# AS3 unwanted delay between playing audio

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, delay

I have a song chopped up into 4 pieces: intro, A, B, ending. I have a program that plays the intro, then the A two times then B two times then back to A again and keeps repeating AABB until I press the ending button. If the ending button is pressed, it finishes the currently playing song piece, plays the ending and stops. It works like a charm except there is a very noticeable, irritating delay in the transition between the song pieces. How can I get rid of the delay and make it play the song pieces right after the previous piece ends? (I'm using actionscript 3.0 in flash cs6, the song pieces are in mp3 format, imported into the library).
Here's the program:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/6f9w906x9uja683/Loop%20music%20test.swf
And here's the code I'm using:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();
//variables
var track_var: Number = 0;
var music_cnl:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var intro_msc:Sound = new intro_mp3();
var a_msc:Sound = new A_mp3();
var b_msc:Sound = new B_mp3();
var outro_msc:Sound = new ending_mp3();
//stopping the movieclips
a_mc.stop();
b_mc.stop();
ending_btn.stop();

//intro
music_cnl = intro_msc.play();
track_var= 1;
intro_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
music_cnl.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playnext_fn);
trace("debug:track value set to",track_var);

//track selector
function playnext_fn(event:Event){
    trace("debug:playnext_fn called");
    switch(track_var){
        case 0:
            //stop
            music_cnl.stop();
            intro_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            a_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            b_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            ending_btn.gotoAndStop(1);
            trace("debug:track value set to",track_var);
            ending_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ending_fn);
        break;
        case 1:
            //first A track
            track_var=2;
            intro_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            b_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            a_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
            music_cnl= a_msc.play();
            music_cnl.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playnext_fn)
            trace("debug:track value set to",track_var);
        break;
        case 2:
            //second A track
            track_var=3;
            music_cnl= a_msc.play();
            music_cnl.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playnext_fn);
            trace("debug:track value set to",track_var);
        break;
        case 3:
            //first B track
            track_var = 4
            a_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            b_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
            music_cnl= b_msc.play();
            music_cnl.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playnext_fn);
            trace("debug:track value set to",track_var);
        break;
        case 4: 
            //second B track
            track_var=1;
            music_cnl= b_msc.play();
            music_cnl.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playnext_fn);
            trace("debug:track value set to",track_var);
        break;
        case 5:
            //ending
            a_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            b_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            intro_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            ending_btn.gotoAndStop(2);
            music_cnl=outro_msc.play();
            track_var=0;
            music_cnl.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playnext_fn);
            trace("debug:track value set to",track_var);
        break;

    }
}

//ending button
ending_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ending_fn);
function ending_fn(Event:MouseEvent){
    track_var=5;
    ending_btn.gotoAndStop(2)
    trace("debug: ending button pressed|","track value set to",track_var);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with your code (other than the redundant and incorrect syntax regarding 
MAX_BUFFERSIZE, but I think this just looks like remnants of trying to resolve the problem!)

What I think is more likely to be causing the problem is your source audio - if it's imported as an MP3, or [with a bitrate of 48](http://www.streaminglearningcenter.com/blogs/48-khz-audio-can-cause-loss-of-synch-with-flash-playback.html) this can cause problems with synching.

Comment: OH, my goodness. No, that just a leftover from one of my failed attempts to correct the delay. I'll edit my question and get rid of it right away. It's not supposed to be there. Also I'd appreciate if you could advise how to reduce the redundancy.

Answer (score -1):

You can't get rid of the delay using traditional Sound object whether from library, loaded externally, mp3, wav, any bite rate. The Flash Sound API suffers from a bad design and latency is inevitable when playing sounds.

However in your case you might be abe to get away with it by using the SampleEventData and mix together all your tracks. The initial latency can go up to 1000ms but in your case that might be irrelevant since the sync between sound is more important:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSE523B839-C626-4983-B9C0-07CF1A087ED7.html

When playing Sounds in Flash in ANY WAY the latency (the time it takes for the sound to start playing) can go from 60ms to 400ms depending on the system. The recommended industry standard is 30ms making Flash an obsolete technology for any Sound related applications.

Comment: It will take a while to figure out how to use this. Should it work I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you suggesting that instead of chopping up the song and play the pieces in sequence, I should just use the whole song, read the samples out of it and play the very samples in the order I want to play them?

Comment: no you still use pieces of your song but with sampleeventdata you can add those pieces to the flow and sync them perfectly. Is it easy? no but it's the only way. Any other way to play sound in flash will produce a delay when the sound starts.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I'll try it but it will take a while because I'm a beginner and I've never did anything like this before. I'll need to look up the relevant commands and arguments because at the moment I have no idea how to build a flow or how to sync samples. It would help a lot if you could give me a simple example code, please? Like: there's sound_A and sound_B and they are looping in a sequence, let's say: ABBABBABB... How would you play it using sample event data?